# activating celery worker and celery beat on cpanel host permanently

Tags: django, django-models, rabbitmq, task, celery

well i have wrote some tasks in my project and i have configured a celery worker and beat for 'em and everything is fine . i open the terminal run worker and beat and it just works. but this is on my local machine . i have deployed my project on a cpanel host and i've installed rabbitmq celery and everything there and also there i open the terminal of venv(with putty and ssh) and i run worker and beat with command line again and it works fine . but here is the thing . i can't do it cause i have to open my own computer and open 2 terminals and start workers.and when i close 'em workers stop . so how can i make them run permanently on the host ?

Comment: Have you figured this out yet?

Comment: yes i've configured it with supervisor http://supervisord.org/installing.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the solution is with supervisor
check it out http://supervisord.org/installing.html
also you can search whole web and find proper ways to do it .
but totaly that just works fine with supervisor